# send sms from pc via android

Tags: android, linux

I am new to android and I am arch linux user. I want to write a program that will allow me to type sms in my pc and send it via android. I thought I can tether my android with pc and do socket programming. But it unmounts the sdcard from my PC.

If there is any other way or if i am going in the wrong direction,can someone help me by telling where to read and what to read?? Thanks.

Comment: It's been 6 years, did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

And do you really need the SDCard to be mounted from your pc for this?

You can also create a service, waiting for an incoming connection. 
Then a small program on your computer allowing you to connect to your phone, write a String, that is sent to your android, which will send the sms...

Comment: No,I need my sdcard mounted for some other reason. Okay so it is possible to do what you said without tethering ..rite?? I mean only through USB connection..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can now use https://messages.android.com/ to send SMS messages from your PC.

> You can use your computer to chat with your friends via Messages for web, which shows what’s on your Messages mobile app. Messages for web sends SMS messages using a connection from your computer to your phone, so operator fees will apply, just like on the mobile app.

https://support.google.com/messages/answer/7611075

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar stuff using this project: http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/

I have a PC application which sends specific `strings` to my own modified chrome2phone project which does what I need on my phone.

So, you can have the same approach, for instance:

- Your PC application sends an xml/jason/whatever to the google service for chrome2phone
- Your modified chrometophone apk gets the string/url you sent from the pc, and send it thru sms...

**Advantage**: You don't need usb cable or to be in the same network ; as long your pc and your phone have an internet connection, it works.

**Requirement**:

- your device needs to use Froyo or higher.
- internet connection